# How can an App Engine pull queue be simultaneously empty and yet still have an oldest task?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue, pull-queue

I'm confused as to whether my queues are truly empty. From this view, the queue called "squid-pri-0" says it has 14 tasks in the queue:

[image]

but when I click on it, it says it's empty (see below). However, I also see an "old task" that is not blank, making me think it's not really empty. Which numbers / stats should I believe?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should believe the queue is empty.  The console looks for tasks in a more detailed manner when you inspect a queue and will notice the overview approximation and tell you correctly that there is nothing in the queue.

Comment: Well when I inspect the queue, I still see "oldest task" is not blank. So that seems to conflict with the "this queue is empty" message (since if it has an oldest task that hasn't executed yet, that would imply there are tasks still in there).